# Is it possible to determine which ad network(s) is used in ads within android app

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, ads, android-logcat

I want to determine ad networks that some android apps use to show their banner/interstitial ads. Is it possible to determine that? Maybe it is possible by reverse engineering (by extracting apk) or monitoring logs in android studio? Any ideas how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You could packet sniff it. Pretty much impossible to detect too. Use wireshark on your desktop, or if you have adaway on your phone, it can do TCPdump for dns queries.

Also very difficult to obfuscate.

Another way would be to tap on one of the ads, and see the url redirects.

Comment: Tapping didn't work because it redirects immediately to the destination without showing any url! Sniffing packets seems to be good idea! I will try it and let you know.